# Does Ubuntu support D-Link DWA 131?

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I tried Ubuntu version 17 on a live installation. I was happy to see that it was recognizing my wifi adapter. After installing a few updates, I was prompted to restart. Little did I know, that restarting would just refresh the whole thing because I was on a live installation. I was then surprised to see that now, in spite of recognizing my adapter, it was unable to connect to my wireless network. Can anyone provide me further insight on this? Or was this an abnormal one off. I'm interested in flashing Ubuntu for good, but I can't risk bad connectivity. Here are the results from terminal which Jeremy told me to take out. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKXcA.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I just edited my post.  Do check it out.